# Return multiple file paths to use in another function using wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

What I'm trying to do here is select multiple files from within a wxPython frame app and then utilize those file paths within another function within the same wxPython app.  I realize I can use the following code to select multiple files:

```
def OnOpen(self,e)
   dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", "", "", "*.", wx.MULTIPLE)
   if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
      filelist = dialog.GetPaths()
```

So the 'filelist' variable is now a list of the files the user selects.  However, I can't seem to find a way to utilize this list in another function.  I was hoping I could just use a return statement within this function in another function and assign it to a variable, but it doesn't seem to allow me to do this.  I guess this is because I have a button event already using this function.   Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I fully understand the issue here. The `OnOpen` function is an event handler for a button click? So it is executed when button is clicked. A windowed application (like yours using wxPython) is usually event driven, it responds to events like a button click. The main GUI thread loops and analyses events which can be handled by you application. So when you write an application these event handlers are entry points for actions you would like to perform.

I think the best way to do is simply the other function and pass `filelist` in parameter e.g:

```
def OnOpen(self,e)
   dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", "", "", "*.", wx.MULTIPLE)
   if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
      filelist = dialog.GetPaths()
      self.otherFunc(filelist)

def otherFunc(self, filelist):
   "do something here"
```

saving `filelist` to an attribute may be problematic sometimes. As I said you may have multiple entry points which would like to use `filelist` attribute, you have to predict possible problems. But as I said at the beginning - I might have not fully understood your problem.

Another possiblity: maybe your problem is that you would like to actually reuse `OnOpen`? First possibility is to pass `None` as an argument because `e` is not used. Another, better possibility is to define `OnOpen` without `e` argument and change the event binding to `self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonwx.EVT_BUTTON(<some object>, lambda evt: self.OnOpen())`. You explicitly say here that you don't need the `evt` argument.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I tried what you suggested on passing "filelist" as the parameter in the otherFunc but I'm seeing how that will work.  Isn't the "filelist" only a variable within the OnOpen function?  Not seeing how the putting the filelist variable as the parameter suddenly shows the list of file paths assigned to that in the OnOpen function.

Comment: Sorry, but I really can't understand the problem. What do you mean by 'putting the filelist variable as the parameter suddenly shows the list of file paths assigned to that'?

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear here.  Just saying, isn't 'filelist' a local variable to the OnOpen function?  If so, how could I make it an argument to the otherFunc function?

Comment: You just pass it as an argument. I updated the example, sorry for the missing line

Comment: Sorry, I could not get it work that way so I ended up using an attribute instead.  It's a small program so shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Put the list as an attribute in self, or have self contain as an attribute a listener that gets the paths, or call the other function giving it the paths as an argument?